# Sum based on grouping in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a pandas dataframe df which contains:

```
major       men        women        rank

Art         5          4            1
Art         3          5            3
Art         2          4            2
Engineer    7          8            3
Engineer    7          4            4
Business    5          5            4
Business    3          4            2
```

Basically I am needing to find the total number of students including both men and women as one per major regardless of the rank column. So for Art for example, the total should be all men + women totaling 23, Engineer 26, Business 17.

I have tried

```
df.groupby(['major_category']).sum()
```

But this separately sums the men and women rather than combining their totals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add both columns and then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
(df.men+df.women).groupby(df.major).sum()

major
Art         23
Business    17
Engineer    26
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

[`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) then [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.drop('rank',1).melt('major').groupby('major',as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
      major  value
0       Art     23
1  Business     17
2  Engineer     26
```